# Cloud code (javascript) failed wtih: {"code":1,"message":"internal error"}

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
if(req.query.currentPosition) {
   console.log("[DEBUG] My current position: " + req.query.currentPosition);
   var maxRadius = 10;
   var coordinates = req.query.currentPosition.split(",");
   var latitude = parseFloat(coordinates[0]);
   var longitude = parseFloat(coordinates[1]);
   var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude});
   query.withinKilometers("coordinates", point, maxRadius);
}
return query.find({});
```

where I read some coordinates from the requests query parameters and I pass those onto a query as a geolocation constraint. Whenever the code runs I get the error

> {"code":1,"message":"internal error"}

and nothing more specific. If I remove the above code block, I don't have any error at all.

I've done some research, and I have found that some other developers have also stumbled upon this message, though in a different context.

- https://www.parse.com/questions/cloud-code-failed-with-code-1message
- https://www.parse.com/questions/facebook-login-code-1-internal-error

Yet no satisfying conclusion was reached or provided.

What have I tried so far:

- Multiple redeploys (my favourite)
- adding and removing the "coordinates" columns
- One of the suggestions from the links I found was that it could a parse internal issue, so waited a day or so to see if anything could be magically solved
- Added a ridiculously amount of logs to see if I could print anything that it could give me a better description of what was happening
- Also checked if anything could be wrong with the data
- Compared with other running applications that have the same code block and are working to see what could be wrong.

None of the above proved to be helpful.

**SDK Version**
Parse JavaScript SDK v1.3.3

Any enlightenment is appreciated.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem. I was setting the wrong key when adding the "withinKilometers" constraint.

Cheers